# Decode this text in arabic

Tags: python, decode

I have this following text in string extracted from a byte, received from some device. 
I want to convert this text into Arabic/Urdu

06270631062F0648
.
.
0627 0631 062F 0648

the output should be اردو

here is my code :

```
hexstring = '06270631062F0648'

print(binascii.unhexlify(hexstring).decode('utf-16-le'))
```

i am getting output: `✆ㄆ⼆䠆`

[here is output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkJQO.png)

Comment: You'll have to try something. Wanting is insufficient without effort.

Comment: At least paste the whole string instead of using *...*

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, even if not far. The difference is that in the proposed duplicate, the byte string got from `binascii.unhexlify` is UTF8 encoded, while this one is utf-16-be encoded. So in first one, the conversion can be implicit, while in this one it is not. It **must** be `binascii.unhexlify(hexstring).decode('utf-16-le')`

Comment: i am getting this by trying this code '1/H @SergeBallesta

Comment: You should edit your question by giving the exact et precise content of the input string. I assumed it was `hexstring = "06270631062F0648"`.

Comment: @SergeBallesta yes its hexstring = "06270631062F0648"

Comment: @SergeBallesta but not getting the desired output

Comment: What is your Python version, underlying OS, and *terminal*?

Comment: @SergeBallesta python 3.6 Os windows 10

Comment: I use same system, and I display expected value from IDLE. Are you using CLI Python in a Windows console (AKA CMD window)?

Comment: @SergeBallesta i am using pyCharms

Comment: @SergeBallesta i added the image of my output in post please check

Comment: Ok. Then I can only suggest that you edit your question to write the exact hexstring, the code that you use to display the converted string and what you see. You should also say that you use Python 3.6 on Windows 10 with pyCharm. If you do that I will vote to reopen your question.

Comment: i edited the question @SergeBallesta

Comment: My bad. I wrote correctly `utf-16-be` in my text, but `utf-16-le` in my code example. It should work fine with: `binascii.unhexlify(hexstring).decode('utf-16-be')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, 0627, 0631, 0627 and 0648 are the code points of the individuals characters of the string. So you should use:

- `binascii.unhexlify` to convert the hexadecimal string to a byte string
- `decode('utf-16-be')` to decode the byte string as utf16 big endian

So this code:

```
hexstring = "06270631062F0648"
print(binascii.unhexlify(h).decode('utf-16-be'))
```

gives:

```
اردو
```